# why i am getting 0 inner nodes and 1 terminal in CHAID in Rstudio despite having 3 independent variables

Tags: r

```
Model formula:
motivation ~ gender + Graduation_country + loe

Fitted party:
[1] root: Pure opportunistic (n = 56, err = 19.6%) 

Number of inner nodes:    0
Number of terminal nodes: 1
```

I tried CHAID but I am getting 0 inner node and 1 terminal node despite have three independent variables all transformed to factor

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.